# Auxillary equations having imaginary roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I found this on my differential equations workbook and was unable to see how to derive the part described in the "note" segment. I tried taking A as common multiple but still it did not help

Answer (score 2):

They use trigonometric identities. Note that
$$A\sin (\beta x) + B \cos (\beta x) = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} \left({A\over\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\sin (\beta x) + {B\over\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \cos (\beta x)\right).
$$
Now find an angle $\theta$ such that $\displaystyle\cos\theta = {A\over\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$ and $\displaystyle\sin\theta = {B\over\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$; $\theta$ exists and is unique if you also require that $0\le \theta < 2\pi$. Then, using the identity
$$\sin (\beta x + \theta) = \cos \theta \sin (\beta x) + \sin \theta \cos (\beta x)$$
Hence
$$A\sin (\beta x) + B \cos (\beta x) = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} \sin(\beta x + \theta),$$
which is of the form $A\sin(\beta x+B)$. You can get a similar form for cosine, and having an extra factor of $e^{ax}$ does not make the manipulation any more difficult.

Comment: So the constant A and B are not as same as it was in the the preceeding equation?

Comment: No, and that was probably a source of confusion.

Comment: So, maybe i should put a "dash " in front of the constants to differentiate them

Comment: Or something to show that you don't necessarily have $A=A$ and $B=B$.

Comment: @AyanShah "So the constant A and B are not the same as in the preceding equation?" Quote: *after suitably adjusting constants*.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  (C_{1}+C_{2})\cos \beta x+(C_1-C_2)i\sin \beta x &= R\cos (\beta x+\phi) \\
  &= R\cos \beta x\cos \phi-R\sin \beta x \sin \phi \\
  R\cos \phi &= C_{1}+C_{2} \\
  R\sin \phi &= (C_{2}-C_{2})i \\
  R^{2} &= (C_{1}+C_{2})^{2}-(C_{2}-C_{2})^{2} \\
      R &= 2\sqrt{C_{1}C_{2}} \\
  \tan \phi &= \frac{C_{2}-C_{1}}{C_{1}+C_{2}}i
\end{align*}

Comment: I did not get your point

Comment: Avoid ambiguity, using $R$ and $\phi$ instead of $A$ and $B$,  Then comparing coefficients for $\cos$ and $\sin$.  $a\sin x+b\cos x \equiv c\sin x+d \cos x \iff a=c$ and $b=c$.